# Unable to hide TitleBar, becomes transparent

Tags: android

I want to delete the title bar from my app, but when use the following code, the title bar isn't hidden, in fact it becomes transparent and the content is pushed downwards:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

So, I have a gap where the title bar used to be (between the notification bar and the app).
I have searched everywhere but haven't found something similar.

**Edit:**

I have tried both of the solutions given by seretum and harism (shown below) but I'm still unable to find the problem, this is a part of my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:src="@drawable/main"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Somehow, the ImageView isn't aligned to the Top of the relative layout...

**Last Edit. SOLUTION:**

So, I tinkered with the xml and found out that when you set a custom dimension to a widget and so use the Realtuve Layout; no matter if the Title bar is present or not, the Widget will always be under it. So, here is the solution (you need to put the object in a layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:maxHeight="155dp"
android:maxWidth="480dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: Also, I have a RelativeLayout and using an ImageView to be at top of the parent. And the ImageView is the one pushed down. The gap is filled with the layout background color, thats how I know its transparent.

Comment: Both solutions you have been supplied so far are correct. You have something else broken in your layout, or are using some theme that is interfering, or something. Use `hierarchyviewer` (or the Hierarchy View perspective in DDMS) to get a better handle on what's going on.

Comment: I edited the post to show the xml code. I still cannot solve this issue!

Comment: Try replacing the `ImageView` with something like a `TextView`. If the `TextView` works, then your problem is with the image itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare So I tried that with a TextView, a Button, a child Layout, and the behavior remained... But I found a solution, I edited the post...

Comment: Thanks very much for this solution, had me stumped for quite a while with the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried requesting no title in different order;

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your app's AndroidManifest.xml, inside the "application" tag, put

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

That will remove your bar from every activity.

Comment: Strange! I've used that always, in a couple of apps, and it worked every time. Tried placing it inside the activity tag instead? Because that should do the trick, it seems your activity is overriding the "no title request"

Comment: I know, it's pretty weird, because I'm not sure what happens, it seems like the Layout is filling the space where the title bar used to be, but the content within the layout is not using that space...